# Comparing Structs with floating point numbers in rust

Tags: testing, struct, rust, floating-point, precision

My tests fail when using floating point numbers `f64` due to precision errors.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c63967bf595565011cf791b18013966a):

```rust
use std::ops::Sub;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Copy)]
struct Audio {
    amp: f64,
}

impl Sub for Audio {
    type Output = Self;

    fn sub(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            amp: self.amp - other.amp,
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn subtract_audio() {
    let audio1 = Audio { amp: 0.9 };
    let audio2 = Audio { amp: 0.3 };

    assert_eq!(audio1 - audio2, Audio { amp: 0.6 });
    assert_ne!(audio1 - audio2, Audio { amp: 1.2 });
    assert_ne!(audio1 - audio2, Audio { amp: 0.3 });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
---- subtract_audio stdout ----
thread 'subtract_audio' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Audio { amp: 0.6000000000000001 }`,
 right: `Audio { amp: 0.6 }`', src/lib.rs:23:5
```

How to test for structs with floating numbers like `f64` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Your problem isn't so much with your implementation of `Sub` as it is with the derived implementation of `PartialEq`.  Better to manually implement, testing that the value is within your desired tolerance.

Comment: @eggyal  I understand floating point, thank you. Would you say implementing `PartialEq` is better than the Answer I posted? thanks.

Comment: The derived `PartialEq` implementation is pretty useless for a struct containing a float, and is likely to lead to unexpected and hard to track down bugs—so I'd definitely suggest removing it.  If the struct nevertheless needs to implement `PartialEq` for other reasons, then you'll need to do it manually anyway... after which your original `assert_eq` will work as expected.  If you don't have any other reason to implement `PartialEq` then I guess it's up to you which approach you use, but I think implementing the trait captures the intent more clearly.

Comment: Of course, if your tolerances during comparisons depend on context, then implementing `PartialEq` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: no they don't depend on context, I want to compare with same accuracy everywhere. thank you @eggyal, I would +1 if I could

Answer (score 2):

If the comparing were to be done with numbers without struct,

```rust
let a: f64 = 0.9;
let b: f64 = 0.6;

assert!(a - b < f64:EPSILON);
```

But with structs we need to take extra measures.
First need to derive with `PartialOrd` to allow comparing with other structs.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct Audio {...}
```

next create a struct for comparison

```rust
let audio_epsilon = Audio { amp: f64:EPSILON };
```

now I can compare regularly (with `assert!` not `assert_eq!`)

```rust
assert!(c - d < audio_epsilon)
```

An other solution is to implement `PartialEq` manually:

```rust
impl PartialEq for Audio {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        (self.amp - other.amp).abs() < f64::EPSILON
    }
}
```

Comment: Nb, unless you know that the LHS is always greater than the RHS (so the subtractions is always positive) you’ll need to take its *absolute value* before comparing against your desired tolerance.

Comment: @eggyal `-5--5 == 0`, unless you talk about possible overflow here yeah it's possible but I choice to keep it simple for a case that should never happen for f64. But yeah production code may want to avoid any risk.

Comment: @Stargateur: If `c` (or `self.amp`) is less than `d` (or `other.amp`) then `c - d` (or `self.amp - other.amp`) will be negative and thus necessarily less than `f64::EPSILON` irrespective of by how much they differ.

Comment: @Stargateur: FYI I rolled back your latest edit because `.abs()` was perfectly fine.

Comment: note that `f64:EPSILON` might not be the right thing to use here.  e.g. you will have less precision if the intermediate values were significantly larger than 1, or involved a large number of intermediate calculations.  note that it's fine given the values in the question, but in general might not do what you expect